# define messages based on locale in hibernate validations

Tags: spring, hibernate, lombok

I am trying to use validation error messages to be based on the current active locale as follows

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "footable")
public class TestModel extends BaseEntity {
   @NotEmpty(message = "${notEmpty}")
   private String name;
}
```

However it doesn't seem to be able to resolve properties, I get

`EL expression '${notEmpty}' references an unknown property`

I have `notEmpty` defined in both `messages.properties` and `application.properties`

I also tried using `@Value` from `lombok` that results in a compile time error rather than a runtime error as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to your config

```
@Bean
public ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasename("classpath:messages");
    messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    return messageSource;
}

@Bean
public LocalValidatorFactoryBean validatorFactoryBean() {
    LocalValidatorFactoryBean validatorFactoryBean = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    validatorFactoryBean.setValidationMessageSource(messageSource());
    validatorFactoryBean.setApplicationContext(context);
    return validatorFactoryBean;
}
```

Remove message from annotation

```
public class TestModel extends BaseEntity {
    @NotEmpty
    private String name;
}
```

To the `messages.properties` add message as

```
NotEmpty.testModel.name=The message of error
```

The name `NotEmpty.testModel.name` follows the [naming convention](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.1.3.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/DefaultMessageCodesResolver.html).

Answer (score 0):

No need for the `$`, use `message = "{notEmpty}"` instead .

Comment: Can you show your Spring configuration file ? 
Have you declared your messageSource and messageSourceAccessor in Spring configuration ?

Comment: were you referring to spring context file? i have no such file because i am using spring-boot